# CGAffineTransform rotation goes the wrong way

Tags: iphone, rotation, cgaffinetransform

In my experiment, i conclude these:

```
YourView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( positive value );
```

will rotate the view clockwise, and

```
YourView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( Negative value );
```

will rotate the view counterclockwise,

But the document says:

The angle, in radians, by which to rotate the affine transform. In iOS, a positive value specifies counterclockwise rotation and a negative value specifies clockwise rotation.

does those contradict with each other?

Comment: ive tested it just now and i get the same results. the documents do specify that in OSX it has this behaviour. but not in ios like you said, very weird.

Comment: Do your `value`happen to be π/2?

Comment: @ibeitia: yes, i tried π/2 and -π/2

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your confusion is quite understandable.

In truth, a positive angle represents a rotation from the positive X axis toward the positive Y axis.  A negative angle represents a rotation from the positive X axis toward the negative Y axis.

The “native” Core Graphics coordinate system is modeled after the standard [Cartesian coordinate system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system), in which the Y axis increases **upward** on the page.  In this system, a positive angle represents a counter-clockwise rotation:

[image: normal coordinate system]

So if you create your own `CGContext` (for example, by using `CGBitmapContextCreate` or `CGPDFContextCreate`), rotations will work as you expect.

However, computer systems have historically used a coordinate system in which the Y axis increases **downward** on the page.  In a flipped coordinate system like this, a positive angle represents a clockwise rotation:

[image: flipped coordinate system]

Notice that in both coordinate systems, a positive angle rotates from the positive X axis toward the positive Y axis.

It turns out that UIKit flips the coordinate system of the graphics contexts that it creates for you.  This includes the graphics context it sets up before sending you `drawRect:` and the graphics context it sets up in `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`.  (The [*Quartz 2D Programming Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_overview/dq_overview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH202-CJBBAEEC) explains this.)  You can check this by looking at the current transform matrix (using `CGContextGetCTM`).  You will find that it has a `-1` in its `d` element, meaning that the Y axis is flipped.

A `UIView` also uses a flipped coordinate system for laying out its subviews, which affects the meaning of the `UIView` `transform` property.

Comment: but in a flipped coordinate system like that, a positive angle represents a clockwise rotation, but the documents say "In iOS, a positive value specifies counterclockwise rotation." So i think it's still contradictive. Is the document wrong?

Comment: It's wrong sometimes.  It depends on the context in which you use the transform.

Comment: @romox It is likely that you were reading something like [this](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/1455666-cgaffinetransformmakerotation). That is a CoreGraphics documentation, but you are in UIKit coordinate system, not in a Core Graphics coordinate system so everything seems correct. Read more in this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41126766/3402095).