# Drawing arc in current context

Tags: ios, core-graphics, quartz-2d

I trying to draw custom arc in current context, but the result is not what i expected to see, i have the simple lines of code if draw method.

```
-(void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextSetGrayFillColor(context, 1.0, 0.7);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 100,100);
    CGContextAddArc(context, 100, 100, 80, 0, M_PI_2, 0);
    CGContextClosePath(context);
    CGContextFillPath(context);
}
```

and here is the result.
[image]

But I'm was expected to see result like this. Why M_PI_2 appears on bottom side of the circle? there should be a 3*M_PI_2, what I'm doing wrong?  [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is explained under [“Coordinate Systems and Drawing in iOS” in the *Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH14-SW14):

> Each of the drawing frameworks of iOS establishes a default coordinate system based on the current graphics context. In iOS, there are two main types of coordinate systems:
>
> - An upper-left-origin coordinate system (ULO), in which the origin of drawing operations is at the upper-left corner of the drawing area, with positive values extending downward and to the right. The default coordinate system used by the UIKit and Core Animation frameworks is ULO-based.
> - A lower-left-origin coordinate system (LLO), in which the origin of drawing operations is at the lower-left corner of the drawing area, with positive values extending upward and to the right. The default coordinate system used by Core Graphics framework is LLO-based.

A positive angle (like `M_PI_2`) represents a rotation from the positive X axis toward the positive Y axis.  So in the graphics contexts given to you by UIKit, a positive angle rotates down.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11732675/77567).

Comment: so UIKit automatically rotate the (LLO)  coordinate system right?