# About CGAffineTransformMakeRotation rotation direction?

Tags: ios, cgaffinetransform

I'm trying to use CGAffineTransformMakeRotation, and I refer Apple document which says

> The angle, in radians, by which this matrix rotates the coordinate system axes. **In iOS, a positive value specifies counterclockwise rotation and a negative value specifies clockwise rotation**. In OS X, a positive value specifies clockwise rotation and a negative value specifies counterclockwise rotation.

So, I pass parameter 90 degree, it should counterclockwise rotation.
self.myView is gray background color view, and red square view is just for see rotation direction

```
#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(x) (x * M_PI/180.0)
CGAffineTransform rotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90) );
[self.myView setTransform:rotation];
```

[image: Before Rotation]
[image: After Rotation]

But why it clockwise rotation?
I'm trying use in simulator and device both have the same result, clockwise rotation
And then tring to use animation:

```
#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(x) (x * M_PI/180.0)
CGAffineTransform rotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90) );
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                 animations:^{
                     self.myView.transform = rotation;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGAffineTransform(self.myView.transform));
                 }];
```

It has the same result, clockwise rotation.

Can somebody explain why, Thanks for the reply.

Comment: My guess is an error in the documentation.

Comment: Where is the link to the documentation you quoted?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGAffineTransformMakeRotation

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is an error in documentation.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGAffineTransformMakeRotation) they describe matrix and provide equations which they use to do the transform:

[image]

If you do the math, you'll see that **for positive angles**, it gives rotation **counterclockwise** when *Y* axis direction is upwards as **in OS X** and **clockwise** when *Y* axis directed downwards as **in iOS**

For example you may try to transform point (5,0) with 90 degrees, you will get (0,5), which means clockwise for iOS and counterclockwise for OS X.

The same piece of documentation still have the (false) part you quoted:

> In iOS, a positive value specifies counterclockwise
>   rotation and a negative value specifies clockwise rotation. In OS X, a
>   positive value specifies clockwise rotation and a negative value
>   specifies counterclockwise rotation.

Which is clearly **wrong**, because the equations (which are the part of the same document and are pretty [standard rotation equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix)) say the opposite.

Comment: Idk about it being wrong. You have to remember you're in UIKit's coordinate system, not the standard one. To get to the standard one, you'd need to flip over the x-axis. At that point (you can picture it in your head) it's rotating counterclockwise.

Answer (score 8):

This is actually correct behavior, and the documentation describes it correctly.

You're dealing with two different coordinate systems here. Core Graphics' coordinate system has (0, 0) on the bottom left, but UIKit's coordinate system has (0, 0) on the top left. Both coordinate systems have an X-axis with 0 on the left. In other words, UIKit's coordinate system is the Core Graphics coordinate system flipped vertically. The following image demonstrates the difference:

[image: Comparison of UIKit and Core Graphics coordinate systems]

---

Now, let's look at your quote:

> The angle, in radians, by which this matrix rotates the coordinate
>   system axes. In iOS, a positive value specifies counterclockwise
>   rotation and a negative value specifies clockwise rotation.

At first glance that seems wrong, but you've missed something. This is a quote from the [CGAffineTransformMakeRotation reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/1455666-cgaffinetransformmakerotation). This is part of the *Core Graphics* reference, not the UIKit reference. It's referring to the rotation as counterclockwise *in Core Graphics' coordinate system*.

You can picture this rotation in your head by flipping what you're seeing on screen vertically and imagining what the rotation would look like.

In fact, the CGAffineTransformMakeRotation reference has a [discussion item](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/1455666-cgaffinetransformmakerotation#discussion) which goes on to document this:

> The actual direction of rotation is dependent on the coordinate system
>   orientation of the target platform, which is different in iOS and
>   macOS.

---

The [discussion item on CGContext's rotate(by:) method reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgcontext/1456228-rotate#discussion) describes this behavior a little better:

> The direction that the context is rotated may appear to be altered by
>   the state of the current transformation matrix prior to executing this
>   function. For example, on iOS, a UIView applies a transformation to
>   the graphics context that inverts the Y-axis (by multiplying it by
>   -1). Rotating the user coordinate system on coordinate system that was previously flipped results in a rotation in the opposite direction
>   (that is, positive values appear to rotate the coordinate system in
>   the clockwise direction).

Answer (score 7):

To get anti-clockwise rotation.. make ur angle in -ve
eg:

*

```
imageToBeRotated.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-angle); // for anti-clockwise rotation
imageToBeRotated.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle); // for clockwise rotation
```

*

Comment: This is what the poster does, and what the documentation says, but as several have noted, the documentation appears to be wrong. Did you actually run this code and see it work?

Comment: @tooluser, This answer is not contradicting the OP or Serhii Yakovenko's answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717634/swift-how-can-you-rotate-text-for-uibutton-and-uilabel/28717635#28717635 for another example.

Comment: Yeah I'm running code like this right now and it does not work as you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Don't get confuse. Its wrong in apple documentation.

CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-angle) // for anti-clockwise rotation
CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle) // for clockwise rotation

Comment: Not if the angle is bigger than 180 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple code to rotate image in diffrent direction.

```
int Count==1;
- (IBAction)Btn_Image:(id)sender {
if (Count==1) {
    Count = Count + 1;
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:self.Img_Selected.CGImage scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationRight];
    self.Img_Canvas.image = image;
}
else if (Count == 2) {
    Count = Count + 1;
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:self.Img_Selected.CGImage scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationDown];
    self.Img_Canvas.image = image;
}
else if (Count == 3) {
    Count = Count + 1;
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:self.Img_Selected.CGImage scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationLeft];
    self.Img_Canvas.image = image;
}
else if (Count == 4) {
    Count = 1;
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:self.Img_Selected.CGImage scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
    self.Img_Canvas.image = image;
}}
```