# rotate 180 degree for an UIImageView, and rotate back with same route

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, core-animation

I got a button and want to rotate the image inside it:

`self.DashButton.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);`

The image is a up-arrow to down-arrow after user click it
When clicking the button again, I want the down-arrow rotate to up-arrow again, but it is the same counterclockwise rotation, but I just want the arrow reverse back to up-arrow

rotate back code:

`self.DashButton.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;`

I tried

`self.DashButton.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI);`

What I want is not rotate the full circle, just 180 rotate and -180 rotate, not a 360 full rotate

Comment: `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-0);`?

Comment: I have finished my answer. check it out. -0 does not help

Answer (score 21, accepted):

instead of -M_PI, use -3.14159. Kind of a trick, but below code saved my day.

```
self.DashButton.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
self.DashButton.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI - 3.14159);
```

Comment: This works as CoreAnimation calculates shortest transformation, and as a rounded pi is used the shortest transform is to reverse the rotation. Yet, in practice the rotation seems indistinguishable from using pi.

Answer (score 7):

```
self.DashButton.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
self.DashButton.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 6):

what you need is a negative angle to rotate it in the opposite direction

CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( 180 * CGFloat(M_PI/180))

CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-1 * CGFloat(M_PI/180))

take a look at this answer for an explanation [About CGAffineTransformMakeRotation rotation direction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731737/about-cgaffinetransformmakerotation-rotation-direction)

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4 version of @Maria working answer

Rotate 180 degrees counter clockwise:

```
let transform = CGAffineTransform.identity

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
      // to rotate counterclockwise set both of these in this exact order
      self.button.transform = transform.rotated(by: 180 * CGFloat(Double.pi))
      self.button.transform = transform.rotated(by: -1 * CGFloat(Double.pi))
}
```

Rotate back 180 degrees clockwise:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { 
      self.button.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
arrowLeft.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(180 *M_PI / 180.0);

arrowLeft.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0*M_PI/180);
```

Comment: No, it does the same as my code. Have you tried it? What I want is not rotate the full circle, just 180 rotate and -180 rotate, not a 360 full rotate

Comment: the idea is not wrong, but rotate 0 still follow the same clockwise, I want the opposite clock.

Comment: @Wingzero Did you want to animate the changes?

Comment: See my answer, just want a 180 degree and a -180 rotate back.

Answer (score 0):

One can also use

```
imageView.image = UIImage(cgImage: imageView.image!.cgImage! , scale: 1.0, orientation: .down)
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
self.DashButton.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
self.DashButton.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 2);
```

it works on my code :)

Answer (score 0):

### Swift 5

```
 //Rotate button 180 degree
 func rotate180(){
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.arrowButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi)
        }
    }
    //Back to normal state again

    func rotateBack(){
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.arrowButton.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

**Swift 3:**

Using `CABasicAnimation`

```
var rotationAnimation = CABasicAnimation()
rotationAnimation = CABasicAnimation.init(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
rotationAnimation.toValue = NSNumber(value: (Double.pi))
rotationAnimation.duration = 1.0
rotationAnimation.isCumulative = true
rotationAnimation.repeatCount = 100.0
view.layer.add(rotationAnimation, forKey: "rotationAnimation")
```

Here is an `extension` functions for UIView that handles start & stop rotation operations:

```
extension UIView {

    func startRotation() {
        let rotation : CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
        rotation.fromValue = 0
        rotation.toValue = NSNumber(value: Double.pi)
        rotation.duration = 1.0
        rotation.isCumulative = true
        rotation.repeatCount = FLT_MAX
        self.layer.add(rotation, forKey: "rotationAnimation")
    }

    func stopRotation() {
        self.layer.removeAnimation(forKey: "rotationAnimation")
    }
}
```

Now using, `UIView.animation` closure:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { 
      button.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (CGFloat(Double.pi))) 
}) { (isAnimationComplete) in
    // Animation completed 
}
```