# How can you rotate text for UIButton and UILabel in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, rotation, uilabel

How can you rotate text for `UIButton` and `UILabel`? 90 degrees, 180 degrees.

**Note:** Before you mark this as a duplicate, I am intentionally modelling my question as a Swift version of this one: [How can you rotate text for UIButton and UILabel in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326720/objective-c-how-can-you-rotate-text-for-uibutton-and-uilabel)

Answer (score 212, accepted):

I am putting my answer in a similar format to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6326768/3681880).

Here is the original label:

[image]

Rotate 90 degrees clockwise:

```
yourLabelName.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2)
```

[image]

Rotate 180 degrees:

```
yourLabelName.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi)
```

[image]

Rotate 90 degrees counterclockwise:

```
yourLabelName.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2)
```

[image]

Do the same thing to rotate a button. Thankfully the touch events also get rotated so the button is still clickable in its new bounds without having to do anything extra.

```
yourButtonName.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2)
```

**Notes:**

Documentation for [CGAffineTransform](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgaffinetransform)

The basic format is `CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat)` where `rotationAngle` is in radians, not degrees.

There are 2π radians in a full circle (360 degrees). Swift includes the useful constant `CGFloat.pi`.

- `CGFloat.pi` = π = 180 degrees
- `CGFloat.pi / 2` = π/2 = 90 degrees

**Auto Layout:**

Auto layout does not work with rotated views. (See [Frame vs Bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28917673/3681880) for an explanation why.) This problem can be solved by creating a custom view. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30952595/3681880) shows how to do it for a `UITextView`, but it is the same basic concept for a label or button. (Note that you will have to remove the `CGAffineTransformScale` line in that answer since you don't need to mirror the text.)

**Related**

- [How to do transforms on a CALayer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34438889/how-to-do-transforms-on-a-calayer)
- [How to apply multiple transforms in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30929986/how-to-apply-multiple-transforms-in-swift)
- [CTM transforms vs Affine Transforms in iOS (for translate, rotate, scale)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30756907/ctm-transforms-vs-affine-transforms-in-ios-for-translate-rotate-scale)

Comment: I did the same for my imageview.But my image getting scaled (small or big).how to do for imageviews..?

Answer (score 20):

If you do this a lot, you'll wan't to make an extension. Also this will allow you to rotate your view 0-360 degrees.

```
extension UIView {
    func rotate(degrees: CGFloat) {
        rotate(radians: CGFloat.pi * degrees / 180.0)
    }

    func rotate(radians: CGFloat) {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: radians)
    }
}
```

Then you can simply call rotate on your views

```
myView.rotate(degrees: 90)
```

Answer (score 7):

## swift

Rotate 90 degrees clockwise:

```
    var rotateLabel: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(100, 0, 28, 159))
    
    rotateLabel.textAlignment = .Right
    
    rotateLabel.text = "Hello!"
    
    self.view.addSubview(rotateLabel)
    
    rotateLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_2))
    
    rotateLabel.frame = CGRectMake(100, 0, 28, 159)
```

Rotate 90 degrees counterclockwise:

```
    var rotateLabel: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(100, 0, 28, 159))
    
    rotateLabel.textAlignment = .Right
    
    rotateLabel.text = "Hello!"
    
    self.view.addSubview(rotateLabel)
    
    rotateLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(-M_PI_2))
    
    rotateLabel.frame = CGRectMake(100, 0, 28, 159)
```

Comment: you have to assign frame again?!

Comment: far easier to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74722372/294884

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using extension with options of degrees and counter/clockwise

```
func rotate(degrees: Int , clockwise: Bool)
{
    let x  = 180 / degrees
    if (clockwise)
    {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi / CGFloat(x))
    }
    else
    {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -CGFloat.pi / CGFloat(x))
    }
}
```

I use it as `extension UILabel {}` but that is obviously up to you

Answer (score 2):

Adapted the answer from Ananthu R Krishnan to fit into Swift 3.1.

Rotate 90 degrees counterclockwise:

```
let rotateLabel: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:15, y:66, width:28, height:159))
rotateLabel.textAlignment = .right
rotateLabel.text = "TEXT"
self.view.addSubview(rotateLabel)
rotateLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(-(Double.pi / 2.0)))
rotateLabel.frame = CGRect(x:15, y:66, width:28, height:159)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a custom font you maybe need:

```
rotateLabel.sizeToFit()
```