# Is there any way to rotate only the text of button in ios

Tags: ios, swift, button, autolayout

i am trying to make a layout, where i don't want to rotate my button, but want to rotate only my text of that button.

So is there any way to do that.?

Comment: You can access button.titleLabel and do something with it.

Comment: Yeah i already tried that.. but i just want to rotate the text of button. so that i dont need to take extra label for all my views.. cz there are bunch of them..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access `button.titleLabel`

example:

```
button.titleLabel?.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2)
```

opposite angle

```
button.titleLabel?.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2)
```

Comment: But angle is not right.. i want the opposite of it.. if you have any idea regarding that..

Comment: My text is clipping when i have more then 2 letters.. Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: @ChaiBiskut Let us continue in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150827/label-cliping-problem)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the original label:

Rotate 90 degrees clockwise:

```
 yourLabelName.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2)
```

Rotate 180 degrees:

```
yourLabelName.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi)
```

Rotate 90 degrees counterclockwise:

```
 yourLabelName.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2)
```

There are 2π radians in a full circle (360 degrees).

Swift includes the useful constant CGFloat.pi.

CGFloat.pi = π = 180 degrees

CGFloat.pi / 2 = π/2 = 90 degrees

Comment: You can mention [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717634/swift-how-can-you-rotate-text-for-uibutton-and-uilabel) of this answer