# How can you rotate Text, Button, Rectangle in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui

How can you rotate `Text`, `Button` and other design controlls of SwiftUI by 90 degrees using SwiftUI?

I am intentionally modeling my question as a SwiftUI version of this one: [How can you rotate text for UIButton and UILabel in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717634/how-can-you-rotate-text-for-uibutton-and-uilabel-in-swift)

**Current output:**

[image: Current output]

**Expected output:**

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use any one of the `.rotationEffect()` methods to rotate any `View` clockwise, including `Button` and `Text`.

For example, this rotates `Text` about its origin (the center of its frame):

```
Text("Turtle Rock")
.rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 90)))
```

Use the overloaded method with an anchor argument to rotate around a different point.

For example, this rotates `Text` about the bottom left point of its frame:

```
Text("Turtle Rock")
.rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 90), anchor: .bottomLeading)
```

You can also use radians for rotation:

```
Text("Turtle Rock")
.rotationEffect(radians: Double.pi / 2)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked as expected.

Comment: Quick note since I just stumbled upon this: your first example should be `Text("Turtle Rock").rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 90))`

Comment: Is it possible to rotate each individual character in the string without rotating the whole string?

Comment: @lochiwei I don't think there's a built in way, but you could easily create your own view that does it. It could just have a string as a parameter, and then iterate over the letters of the string with a `ForEach` inside an `HStack`, and rotate the individual `Text`s for each letter.

Answer (score 0):

To do any kind of (complex) rotation, use 3D as `.rotation3DEffect(.degrees(45), axis: (x: 0.5, y: 0, z: 0))` (that would be StarWars credits effect).
These two should be equivalent: `Text("Turtle Rock").rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 90)))` and `Text("Turtle Rock").rotation3DEffect(.degrees(90), axis: (x: 0, y: 0, z: 1))`