# How to create a label upside down and text facing towards the page

Tags: swift, xcode, label

I need to create Copywrite label which is starting from the bottom and ending at the top, It's easy to do the same with transformation if the text is not facing towards the right, But how to do the below-attached

[[image: its the image 1]

Ideally,[image] it should look like above

Comment: Could you give another example of how this is supposed to look? Especially in the context of other surrounding views.

Comment: I added @ParthTamane

Comment: What happens if you do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717634/how-can-you-rotate-text-for-uibutton-and-uilabel-in-swift and pass -90 to answer by @drees

Comment: @ParthTamane , it worked with    let copywriteText = "Meditec- Copyright 2018 All rits reserved"
        let copyWriteLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 300, width: 300, height: 17))
        copyWriteLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2)
        copyWriteLabel.text = copywriteText
        copyWriteLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        self.view.addSubview(copyWriteLabel)

Comment: Thought so. If you want to do such transformations often then you should use the extension method in the link I sent.